# (Java) W/MirrorManager: this model don't Support Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

[image]

**Error Logs : **

I/BufferQueueProducer: ViewRootImpl[MainActivity]#0(BLAST Consumer)0 connect: api=1 producerControlledByApp=true

D/n.backgroundjo: MiuiProcessManagerServiceStub setSchedFifo

I/MiuiProcessManagerImpl: setSchedFifo pid:5607, mode:3

D/hw-ProcessState: Binder ioctl to enable oneway spam detection failed: Invalid argument

E/OpenGLRenderer: fbcNotifyFrameComplete error: undefined symbol: fbcNotifyFrameComplete

E/OpenGLRenderer: fbcNotifyNoRender error: undefined symbol: fbcNotifyNoRender

D/DecorView[]: onWindowFocusChanged hasWindowFocus true

E/BLASTBufferQueue: ViewRootImpl[MainActivity]#0 isEGL=1, mPendingRelease.size()=1, mMaxAcquiredBuffers=4, currentMaxAcquiredBufferCount=2

E/BLASTBufferQueue: ViewRootImpl[MainActivity]#0 isEGL=1, mPendingRelease.size()=2, mMaxAcquiredBuffers=4, currentMaxAcquiredBufferCount=2

W/System: A resource failed to call close.